# Is there a method to simulate (.NotDetermined) status from ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am developing an App and testing on my physical iPhone.

At some point, the app checks if it is authorized to view the contacts (address book) of the phone using `ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus()`.

That call returns a status which can either be `.Denied,.Authorized,.Restricted, .NotDetermined`.

The last one is returned if you run the app for the first time, and have never approved or denied the app from accessing the device's address book.

Once you answer that authorization question, that answer is stored somewhere, and in the future, you will either get a `.Authorized` or `.Denied` status. Never again a `.NotDetermined`.

I tried deleting the app, and installing again. I tried changing the compile settings and changed the target build iOS. I did a Clean build, but I failed to get that status again.

I know I can copy the Xcode project and name the app something different to trick the iPhone into thinking this is a new app. But what is a straight forward way to let the app receive a `.NotDetermined` status again?

Answer (score 4):

Go into the General settings and Reset Location and Privacy. (This will have other side effects, but there's nothing you can do about that.)